# How to Position Tooltip in D3 Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm adding tooltips to a D3 scatter plot and I'm not sure exactly how to position them. They're appearing far to the left of the chart. I thought they'd be nested inside my chart div, so that the `style: left` would handle it. The height looks okay to me. [image: 401k calculator screenshot]

Relevant code:

```
                        d3.select("#chart")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("height",height)
                        .attr("width",width)
                        .style("background","#3A5FCD")
                        .selectAll("circle").data(employeecontributionaged)
                        .enter().append("circle")
                        .attr('cx',function(d,i) {
                            return i*(barWidth + barOffset);
                        })
                        .attr('cy',function(d) {
                           return height-yScale(d)
                        })
                        .attr('r',5)
                        .attr("fill","#000000")
                        .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {        
                                div.transition()
                                    .duration(50)
                                    .style("opacity", .9);
                                div.html("Age: " + i + "<br>Employee Contribution Value: " + d.formatMoney(2,'.',','))
                                    .style("left", i*(barWidth + barOffset) + "px")
                                    .style("top", height-yScale(d) + "px");
                            })
                            .on("mouseout", function (d) {
                                div.transition()
                                    .duration(50)
                                    .style("opacity", 0);
                            })
```

Tooltip CSS:

```
div.tooltip {   
    position: absolute;         
    text-align: center;         
    width: 80px;                    
    height: 100px;                  
    padding: 2px;               
    font: 12px sans-serif;      
    background: lightsteelblue; 
    border: 0px;        
    border-radius: 8px;         
    pointer-events: none;   
    color: white;       
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zynLryyL/

Comment: How is the tooltip div positioned? It should be absolute.

Comment: It is. I've added the CSS above.

Comment: Positioning is tough. I would look at using https://www.npmjs.com/package/tippy.js which is powered by https://www.npmjs.com/package/popper.js  Popper is a positioning engine used by a lot of folks. Let it do the work for you.

Comment: Position its parent as well i.e. `div#chart { position: relative;}`. It'll then get absolute positioned **relative** to its parent. Here's a fork: https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2104/zynLryyL/8/